# Pickle File not found while loading

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, scikit-learn, pickle

I have saved a classifier model with pickle using the following code-

```
import pickle
with open('model.pickle', 'wb') as fid:
    pickle.dump(clf, fid)
```

This is the score.py file where I am loading the pickle model and the same file is called during deployment. Also note that, all these files (code, pickle file and related files) are in the same directory.

```
# Initialize the deployment environment
def init():
    global obj
    with open('./model.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        obj = pickle.load(f)
```

This is getting stored in some directory `var/azureml-app`

After running this deployment code, this is the error I am getting-

```
open('/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/model.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/batch/tasks/model.pickle'
```

Comment: [Pickle Load- File Not Found when deploying using Azure ML Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/861537/pickle-load-file-not-found-when-deploying-using-az.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way to solve this error.

Instead of loading the model as

```
 with open('./skm.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        obj = pickle.load(f)
```

You need to load the model as

```
 model_path = os.path.join(os.getenv('AZUREML_MODEL_DIR'), 'skm.pickle')
 model = joblib.load(model_path)
```

The `AZUREML_MODEL_DIR` will take the environment directory of the model where it is stored.

This will solve the error.